# Is it possible to reduce the graphical load on a computer's memory via the Ubuntu command line interface if the bios provides no option to do so?

Tags: command-line, nvidia, graphics, bios

I have just installed Ubuntu Ermine on my Dell Desktop. It is ten years old, and working swimmingly, which is a testament to the OS.

However, the machine leaves artifacts and trails on-screen when things get graphically busy or crowded. Is it possible to reduce the graphical load on a computer's memory via the Ubuntu command line interface if the bios provides no option to do so?

Thank you for considering my question, and forgive me for my early ineptitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use a lightweight desktop environment such as [LXDE](https://lxde.org/) or [XFCE](https://www.xfce.org/). Also, find out which services are running by either going to System Monitor or open terminal and type `htop` to find list of running processes

Comment: thank your for the tips. i particularly like the feel of lxde. regarding htop, the are SO MANY processing. how do I filter out the jobs related to eye candy?